# Python: Put date and time in xls columns

Tags: python, excel, datetime, xls

I would like to export a date to Excel columns

I've got the following code:

```
from xlsxwriter import Workbook
from pathlib import Path
from datetime import date
from datetime import time

#time
Second = 55
Hour = 10
Minute = 11
time_sum = time(Hour, Minute, Second)

#Date
day = 2
year = 2019
month = 11
Date_sum = date(year, month, day)
date = []
date.extend((Date_sum, time_sum))

#write in excel
workbook = Workbook('datetime.xlsx')
Report_Sheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
# Write the column headers.
Report_Sheet.write(0, 0, 'datetime')
# Write the column data.
Report_Sheet.write_column(1, 0, date)
workbook.close()
```

but I got this in Excel:

[image: excel output]

but I would like to have the correct format (date and time) so that the values are directly correct in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use pandas and use the `to_excel` function:

E.g. with the CSV file:

```
string,date,number
a string,2/5/11 9:16am,1.0
a string,3/5/11 10:44pm,2.0
a string,4/22/11 12:07pm,3.0
a string,4/22/11 12:10pm,4.0
a string,4/29/11 11:59am,1.0
a string,5/2/11 1:41pm,2.0
a string,5/2/11 2:02pm,3.0
a string,5/2/11 2:56pm,4.0
a string,5/2/11 3:00pm,5.0
a string,5/2/14 3:02pm,6.0
a string,5/2/14 3:18pm,7.0
```

read in like this:

```
b=pd.read_csv('b.dat')
b['date']=pd.to_datetime(b['date'],format='%m/%d/%y %I:%M%p') #convert col to datetime
```

You can save to excel like this:

```
b.to_excel('yourfile.xls')
```

and it preserves the date format (Tested using libre office calc).

Answer (score 0):

A date in Excel is a number with a format. Currently you have the number but not the format.

To display a date/time you can add a format like this:

```py
workbook = Workbook('datetime.xlsx')
Report_Sheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Make the first column wider for clarity.
Report_Sheet.set_column(0, 0, 20)

datetime_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'dd/mm/yy hh:mm'})

# Write the column headers.
Report_Sheet.write(0, 0, 'datetime')
# Write the column data.
Report_Sheet.write_column(1, 0, date, datetime_format)
workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image]

However, you generally want to have a separate format for dates and time so something like this may be what you need:

```py
workbook = Workbook('datetime.xlsx')
Report_Sheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Make the first column wider for clarity.
Report_Sheet.set_column(0, 0, 20)

date_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'dd/mm/yy'})
time_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'hh:mm'})

# Write the column headers.
Report_Sheet.write(0, 0, 'datetime')
# Write the column data.
Report_Sheet.write(1, 0, Date_sum, date_format)
Report_Sheet.write(2, 0, time_sum, time_format)
workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image]